# Is content URI necessary for web allowed objects?

Tags: webview, uwp

I am learning web allowed objects in the universal application. Previously I am using script notify to know any action on the content in my web view, where i specified the URL of my web view content in the app manifest file. Now I am trying to switch it from script notify to web allowed object. But without specifying any URL in the app manifest it is working as expected. Is is the behavior of the web allowed object or something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

According to *Accessing the Windows Runtime in a web view* section of [`WebView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/web-view) class:

> You can use the [`AddWebAllowedObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.addweballowedobject#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_AddWebAllowedObject_System_String_System_Object_) method to inject an instance of a native class from a Windows Runtime component into the JavaScript context of the WebView. This allows full access to the **native methods**, properties, and events of that object in the JavaScript content of that `WebView`.

So that you may not need to specify URL to make it work with accessing the native methods in Runtime component, but ensure to decorate the class with the `AllowForWeb` attribute.

Specifying any URL you mentioned in the app manifest is for addition features that trusted JavaScript content in `WebView` can be allowed to directly access **Windows RuntimeAPI**. This provides powerful native capabilities for web apps hosted in a web view. For more details about this feature please reference [Accessing UWP features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/hwa-access-features).